# C++ program is giving a too many arguments warning

Tags: c++, printf

I barely know what I'm doing, I have this code where I try to solve some simple math:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

  main()
 {
  int n, sum=0;
  printf("ENTER NUMBER:");
  scanf("%i",n);
  while(n>0)
   {
    sum+=n;
    n--;
   }
    printf("\n sum is:",sum);
   return 0;
 }
```

The problem with it is that when I try to compile it I get this error:

```
main.cpp:23:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]        
printf("\n sum is:", sum);
```

Comment: There is no nested loop here.

Comment: `main()` is a syntax error in C++.

Comment: Please post the errors your are getting with that code. `scanf("%i", n);` should be `scanf("%i", &n);` because the second parameter accepts a pointer, I expect that would be one of the errors...

Comment: Before someone can help you with a problem, you usually have to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Your  `scanf` call isn't right, either.  Since you're using a C++ compiler, you should use the C++ I/O facilities (like `std::cout`, `std::cin`).

Comment: Like @1201ProgramAlarm pointed scanf call should be used like `scanf("%i",&n);`( Address of n must be passed in scanf ). Also `printf` is missing format specifier. read [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). No need to include `#include<conio.h>` and `#include<stdlib.h>`

Comment: As the warning says, `printf("\n sum is:", sum);` doesn't indicate any format specifier, it should be something like `printf("\n sum is: %d", sum);`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is warning you that you forgot to specify the field for sum in the format string. You probably wanted:

```
printf("\n sum is: %d",sum);
```

As above, it will not print the sum, and the sum value will not be used. Hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code (fixes as pointed out in the comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<conio.h> // You don't use anything from these headers (yet?)
//#include<stdlib.h>

//main()
int main() // main has to be defiend as an int function
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    printf("ENTER NUMBER:");
//  scanf("%i", n);
    scanf("%i", &n); // scanf need the ADDRRESS of variables
    while (n > 0)
    {
        sum += n;
        n--;
    }
//  printf("\n sum is:", sum);
    printf("\n sum is: %i", sum); // printf needs a format specifier for each variable
    return 0;
}
```