# Im having a problem with C++ "too many arguments" warning

Tags: c++

I barely know what I'm doing, I have this code where I try to solve some simple math:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

  main()
 {
  int n, sum=0;
  printf("ENTER NUMBER:");
  scanf("%i",n);
  while(n>0)
   {
    sum+=n;
    n--;
   }
    printf("\n sum is:",sum);
   return 0;
 }
```

The problem with it is that when I try to compile it I get this error:

main.cpp:23:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
printf("\n sum is:", sum);

Comment: Why did you post an exact copy of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982176/c-program-is-giving-a-too-many-arguments-warning)? How many Stack Overflow accounts do you have?